# ASCII control of VFD

Tags: controls, ascii

All,

I am a new user here, and thought I would see if the experts could help me with something I am new to.

I have been given the following statement to try and solve:

The Variable Frequency Drive (VFD) is connected to the PLC by RS485 communication. The speed of the motor (M2) can be adjusted by sending the following command:

STX N DATA ETX , with each separate value having the <> symbols around them.

Data : Length of data is 1 byte, in which the value of S (Slow), M (Medium) or F (Fast) can be sent.
N : Node number of the VFD, with a data length of two byte ASCII.

My question is, how would I type to send this data? It doesn't say whether to use a specific data type to represent, so surely I could just type the data as it is, e.g. STX 1 S ETX?

Othwerside, I'm not sure how to combine the byte representations of the data, representing them in hex, binary or decimal. I'm not sure what is meant by two byte ASCII, is this not UNICODE-16? Also, I'm not sure if I need to send the values of STX or ETX with the data string or not

I hope someone can shed some light on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to homework overflow. In order to get some help you should provide your question in the correct way and add some more context information. E.g., what are used software, libraries, etc. and what have you already tried.

Comment: Sim, there isn't anymore context to this unfortunately, that is my issue. It doesn't say which PLC, what software, no libraries, it is just arbitrary system. I have just never had a VFD controlled this way, and wouldn't know how to type ASCII commands, I am aware of the different ASCII and extended ASCII tables, as well as UNICODE etc, but I would not know how to write: <STX><1><S><ETX> in a format to be transferred, surely as it is written is just the ASCII form? It is the fact is it talking about byte and two byte ASCII that makes me think it wants it in a binary form.

Answer (score 1):

Since the frequency goes from 0-50 Hz, I think we should send data in this range.
So if we want the frequency to be half maximal, we will send 25.
To send this to VFD, we first need to split that number into 2 and 5
The message should read STX 2 5 ETX?
Now we look at the ASCII code table and find 2 and 5.
0x50 = 2
0x53 = 5
We convey everything in a message that reads
STX 0x50 0x53 ETX
The aforementioned [S7-300](https://devicebase.net/en/siemens-s7-300) is recommended for operation. You can also solve this through his TIA portal.

Answer (score 0):

All,

I managed to figure this out with a bit of digging. I simulated it using Siemens S7-300 on TIA portal, and set up communications on a module. I sent the values I wanted using a "move" block, to a value set in the Data Block.
I repeated this for the Node value, making sure the correct data type was chosen, and sent the data through a Send_ptp command block.

Must have got a bit flustered and tired the other night when I was trying it. Hopefully it might help someone in the future.